# Return count of unique values from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
event_results = [{'device': 'prod2261.example.com'}, {'device': 'npbodb253.example.com'}, {'device': 'db221.example.com'}, {'device': 'db219.example.com'}, {'device': 'db209.example.com'}, {'device': 'db243.example.com'}, {'device': 'prod277.example.com'}, {'device': 'prod2228.example.com'}, {'device': 'prod2252.example.com'}, {'device': 'prod2116.example.com'}, {'device': 'prod224.example.com'}, {'device': 'db223.example.com'}, {'device': 'db229.example.com'}, {'device': 'prod2116.example.com'}, {'device': 'db221.example.com'}, {'device': 'db239.example.com'}, {'device': 'npbodb249.example.com'}, {'device': 'db210.example.com'}, {'device': 'db219.example.com'}, {'device': 'db243.example.com'}, {'device': 'prod2210.example.com'}, {'device': 'prod224.example.com'}, {'device': 'npbodb253.example.com'}, {'device': 'npbovwa018.example.com'}, {'device': 'npbovwa018.example.com'}, {'device': 'db221.example.com'}, {'device': 'db243.example.com'}, {'device': 'prod2228.example.com'}]
```

I need to obtain the value, and count of the unique values.

Example output needs to be:

```
prod2261.example.com, 2
prod2261.example.com, 5
....etc....
```

So far I can get a set of all unique values:

```
unique_values = set(e['device'] for e in event_results)
```

But I'm struggling to iterate over both lists and return just a count for each item in the unique_values set without creating a bunch of temporary lists and such to store values in and then len() at the end.

I think the solution is something to do with list comprehension, but I just can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just use a `collections.Counter` instead of a `set` and you're done :)

```
import collections
unique_counts = collections.Counter(e['device'] for e in event_results)
```

Comment: wow you're right! Even running `timeit` with the itemgetter in the setup, this is SIGNIFICANTLY slower (11s vs 8s) than the dictionary lookup. I stand thoroughly corrected